# remove an entire array

Tags: java

i am trying to remove records of an employee that contains "?"(null values).  the employee database looks like

34,45,56,?,34
45,67,34,56,56
23,45,67,?,90

using the following code i replaced the entire row that contains "?" with "0".

```
public void doRemoval(String filename)
{
        contents = new Vector();
        inputstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
        String string = "";
        while((string = br.readLine())!= null)
        {
            String[] split = string.split(",");
            Vector vector = new Vector();
            for(int i=0; i<split.length; i++)
                vector.add(split[i].trim());
            if(vector.contains("?"))
            {
                for(int i=0; i<split.length; i++)
                    split[i] = "0";
            }
            contents.add(split);
        }
```

the output is
0,0,0,0,0
45,67,34,56,56
0,0,0,0,0

now i want to remove the rows containing "0".  i don't have an idea of how to do it.  can anyone help me.  all that i want to do is to remove the rows that contain null values.  is there any other way to perform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this:

```
public void doRemoval(String filename)
{
    contents = new Vector();
    inputstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
    String string = "";
    while((string = br.readLine())!= null)
    {
        String[] split = string.split(",");
        Vector vector = new Vector();
        for(int i=0; i<split.length; i++)
            vector.add(split[i].trim());
        if(!vector.contains("?"))
        {
            contents.add(split);
        }

    }
```

You don't remove them, you just don't add them.

Comment: and can you tell me is that possible to replace the null values by mean value of that particular column?

Comment: Yes it is and that is not hard, too. Try to think about it a bit. Tip: first iterate once to compute the mean(actually the number of non-'?' values and their sum) value and then iterate second time to replace the '?'-s. Take care on the case when all values are '?'.

Comment: actually i don't have an idea of how to  read it column vise.

Comment: Go over split before inserting it into contents. At this point you can access separate elements. You may use Integer.ValueOf to convert string to Integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to have the intermediate step with all zeros, you can:

```
if(!vector.contains("?")) {
    contents.add(split);
}
```

instead of the block with:

```
if(vector.contains("?"))
{
    for(int i=0; i<split.length; i++)
    split[i] = "0";
}
contents.add(split);
```